# Android horizontal listview with contents wrapped according to width of layout

Tags: android, listview

I have managed to write the following piece of code:

Following is my listview in the xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/popular_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popular_layout"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</ListView>
```

Here is the code that makes those round borders wrapping the text contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.magicpin.local.buddycloud.customviews.TypefacedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/location_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/select_location_text"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:fontType="@string/font_normal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_location"
    />
```

Here is the code which populates it:

```
ListView popularList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.popular_list);
String[] popularListName = getPlacesName(locations);
ArrayAdapter<String> popularListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.locations_item_layout, popularListName);
popularList.setAdapter(popularListAdapter);
```

which shows me a `ListView` in the following manner:

[image]

Can someone let me know how can I make the bottom `ListView` (i.e., the `POPULAR PLACES` region) show my contents in the manner as shown in the following image (i.e., show it horizontally and wrapped by width, rather than one-by-one vertically) ?

[image]

Comment: share a code where it described

Comment: You're asking for a library.

Comment: Can you show your listview code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the GridView instead of ListView.

Comment: Thanks, Silvi. However, can you please be a bit more specific about this? Like, are there any parameters that I must add in my GridView in order for it to look the way I want it to?

Comment: If you need more specific answer, you have to show your code.

Comment: I did show you my code in the question itself, right? The first xml is the main xml of the page, the second xml is the xml for each item of the adapter, and the 3rd part of the code, shows that I have a list of Strings (`String[] popularListName = getPlacesName(locations);`) which populates the list. I just need to make the items show in a horizontally wrapped manner, rather than normal vertically. Can you please tell me what changes I need to make in my code now, to achieve my goal?

Comment: The `android:background="@drawable/rounded_location"` in the second xml code, simply adds those round borders to the texts before showing them in the list

Comment: Just replace your ListView with GridView, which allows you to have more columns. <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_popular_places"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="2" >
    </GridView>                                                                                                                                     
Then fill the grid cells using Adapter.The next implementation is basically the same as with ListView.

Comment: Thanks, Silvi. So, adding `android:numColumns="2"` to my xml leads to showing only two items in a line. Can you tell me how to make it show the items in each line in a "best-fit" manner? That is, each line showing as many no. of items on it as the line can fit, depending on the size of the items?

Comment: I see. GridView does not support this functionality. You can have only fixed number of columns. For your needs, you have to create your own component. But this is too complex for stack overflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103312/discussion-between-sanjiban-bairagya-and-silvi).

Answer (score 0):

Instead , I would suggest you to use library [TagView Git](https://github.com/Cutta/TagView).

Find sample example in above link, so that it will be easy to implement.

[image]

### Feature

1. Editable Style of Text, such as Font size and color.
2. Editable Style of Tag, Background/Pressed Color, Radius effect,
   Custom Background, Delete mode.
3. Listener of tag selecting and deleting.
4. Can be created from XML file or Java code.

### Usage

```
<cuneyt.example.com.tagview.Tag.TagView
            android:id="@+id/tag_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```